# Gathering all records before changing DNS hosts

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

My organization owns a domain name through Network Solutions. Network Solutions does not host the DNS for us (another company hosts the DNS through RackSpace).

I would like to take ownership of the DNS hosting by using Network Solution's DNS manager but first I need to make sure I have all the records that currently exist on the RackSpace DNS.

Is there a way to definitively gather everything in the RackSpace DNS without having access to the rackspace account so I can safely change the DNS to Network Solution nameservers?

Answer (score 2):

No.  The way to gather everything is called a zone transfer request (an `AXFR` query) - in all but a few rare cases, authoritative DNS servers on the internet will deny these requests.

Getting the contents of the zone through the management interface (or an export of the zone file - not sure what Rackspace offers in this respect) is the only way to be certain to faithfully recreate the zone.